# How can i group the nodes by 5000 elements

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a big xml file.

```
<Users>
 <User id="2" name="ABC">
   <Data>text</Data> 
 </User>
 <User id="3" name="xyz">
   <Data>text</Data> 
 </User> 
 <User id="4" name="LMN"> 
   <Data>text</Data> 
 </User>
 ...
</Users>
```

I need group nodes by 5000 to split it. Some like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=" " group-by="by 5000">
  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@somename}-output.xml">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try along these lines:

```
<xsl:template match="Users">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="User" group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 5000">
    <xsl:result-document href="file{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
      <Users>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </Users>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: One small improvement is to use group-adjacent rather than group-by. Since items making up a group will be adjacent in the input sequence, the implementation can be more efficient, avoiding the need to sort all the input items into buckets before starting to process them.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="*[position() mod 5000 = 1]">
```

That's assuming that the nodes you want to group are siblings, and aren't mixed with other nodes.

Comment: Grouping by position in the sequence, as in Martin's suggestion, is a more general solution.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for this pointer. I had the same thought, but since the OP didn't give any handle by which to refer to the sequence, I didn't bother to try and express that. Rather, I expressed the loss of generality and left it to the OP to say if he was working outside those constraints. Martin made his own (reasonable) assumptions about the sequence, e.g. that it consisted of all `User` children of `Users`, which allowed him to be more concrete, at the cost of some generality.